# How do I add component defaults in angular cli 6+

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

In the old angular cli there was a key called `defaults`:

```
"defaults": {
    "schematics": {
      "collection": "@nrwl/schematics",
      "postGenerate": "npm run format",
      "newProject": [
        "app",
        "lib"
      ]
    },
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {
      "changeDetection": "OnPush"
    }
  }
```

This property no longer exsists.  How do I add component/changeDetection on push in angular cli 6+?  moreover is there a list of component properties I can add?

Comment: For the second part of your question (...is there a list of component properties I can add?), the following link might be helpful: [Angular CLI Config Schema](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not as familiar with the old CLI. Were those properties configured as global CLI settings, or a per-project setting?

In the new Angular CLI, you can replicate per-project settings in the `angular.json` file by updating the `schematics` object to the following:

`"projects": {
    "my-project": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "changeDetection": "OnPush"
        }
      },`

Comment: You can also set the `schematics` sibling to `projects` for defaults for all the projects in the cli dir / repo. And for global (on windows) `C:\Users\[user]\.angular-config.json`

Answer (score 6):

Via the Angular CLI, you can do it as follows:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.changeDetection OnPush
```

Comment: This looks like the official answer, matches the recommendation in the issue - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13327

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in the schematics section of angular.json see schematics: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace I'm not sure if you can directly edit the default schematics for component, or you have to create your own schematic that uses the component schematic, as you see in this tutorial: https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2 (section: Calling Another Schematic).